# .net MAUI write to external storage

Tags: maui, .net-maui

With xamarin forms I wrote to external storage by writing platform specific code. For android using MainActivity.Instance.GetExternalFilesDir for example.

I was assuming that with MAUI, such a common requirement, of writing to external storage, would be built into the framework, but I fail to find any mention of it. Is this really something that still requires per platform coding?

I realize there is the FilePicker, but that seems to be for reading and not for writing.

Comment: ExternalStorage is an Android concept.  What would it do on other platforms?

Comment: I had not really considered that, @Jason, as I have so far always written for android only... Perhaps just have support for enumerating all possible storage locations, that being internal, external on device or external through usb?

I take it you are saying that MAUI does in fact not have built in support for this?

Comment: AFAIK it works the same as in XF.

Comment: With the addition of the FilePicker, though